# textscan returning empty cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv

I have a CSV file with mixed records (both double and string) and a header line of strings in the first row.

I have written the following code to import this csv file into a cell array in MatLAB

```
%Determine Formatspec for CSV file
fid =  fopen('URM_sample.csv')
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n')
str = C{1}{2,:}
nstr = textscan(str,'%s','delimiter',',')

fspec = ''
for i = 1:length(nstr{1}) % Check each string
    if isempty(str2num(nstr{1}{i})) % This string is text
        fspec = [fspec ' %s'];
    else % This string is a number
        fspec = [fspec ' %f'];
    end
end

B = textscan(fid,fspec,'HeaderLines',1,'Delimiter',',')
```

Unfortunatley when I open B all I get is an empty 1x24 cell array, where the original csv is 201x24 (contains 201 records).... Any idea as to what I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say what is wrong withut the csv file. Why don't you use csvread() ? If you need to read some strings, I would advice to use xlsread()

Comment: Show the first few lines of your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the 'delimiter' parameter incorrectly, and also specifying `formatSpec` incorrectly. Try

```
fid =  fopen('URM_sample.csv')
nstr = textscan(fid,'%s %s ... %s','delimiter',',', 
               'HeaderLines', 1, 'EndOfLine', '\n')
```

I believe you need to repeat `%s` 24 times in the `formatSpec` parameter.